# Can't create docker image for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, docker-image, ml.net

**my docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NetCore.Docker.dll"]
```

**the command**

```
docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile.txt .
```

**the error:**

```
E:\TEMP\App>docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile.txt .
time="2020-05-22T14:19:46+03:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\E:\\TEMP\\App\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\NetCore.Docker.exe to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe"
error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcptssii&ccpp=u"220022mm-e0m5s-=&cpushare2s=0&dockerfile=
Dockerfile.txt&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&netw22rTT14:ooddee4=6d+0033::00ll"t &lrmm==1ll==eerrrroorr  mmssgg==""CCaann''tt  cclloossaes tt3aiff 91100iitteerr::  iioo::  rr0e&tt==ccoouunntteerro-
ii ccllooes&ttaarrggeett==&&ulerror during connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcptssii&ccpp=u"220022mm-e0
m5s-=&cpushare2s=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile.txt&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&netw22rTT14:ooddee4=6d+0033::00ll"t &lrmm==1ll==eerrrroorr  mmssgg==""CCaann''tt  cclloossaes tt3aiff 91100iitteerr::  iio
o::  rr0e&tt==ccoouunntteerro-ii ccllooes&ttaarrggeett==&&ulimits=null&version=1: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try increase the Memory and the Swap in settings.

[image: docker settings]